# Geodesics and first fundamental form

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, geodesics

If we consider Hamiltonian $H(p,q)=(1/2)p^TAp$. where $p=(p_1,p_2)$ and $A$ is a symmetric matrix $A_{ii}=e^{q_i^2}+1$ and $A_{12}=A_{21}=1$. Then how I proceed to find the first Fundamental form of a manifolds whose geodesics are trajectories of the hamiltons of Hamiltonian $H$.

I know that $\dot{p}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}$ and $\dot{q}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$. Now how I proceed to find the first fundamental form to geodesics?

Please help me.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/500941/2451

Comment: You should explain what you have learned about the first fundamental form.